# User Login not working with django's default user Authentication

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm new to Django and trying to make user's login to my App using the Django's User Authentication.

The signup is working fine, so there is no problem with my model or signup view (Using class based views). I tried to import LoginView and LogoutView from `Django.contrib.auth.views` and post method has been set in my login template. I can't figure out what I'm missing here. The user won't simply Login, but signup works well.

This is accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', 
auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"),name = 
"login"),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name = "logout"),
path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name = "signup")
]
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.HomePage.as_view(), name = "Home"),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace = "accounts")),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
path('test/', views.TestPage.as_view(), name = "Test"),
path('thanks/', views.ThanksPage.as_view(), name = "Thanks"),
]
```

This is login template inside accounts app (accounts/templates/accounts/login.html)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block mainContent %}

<div class = "container">
<h1> Hello! Lets Login </h1>
<form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" value = "Login"
</form>
</div>

 {% endblock %}
```

This is models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import models

class User(models.User,models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

When I click on Login, nothing happens. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with the code. I just had some syntax error and some the code was incomplete.

First, the end tag for Form was missing.

Second, I added form action to like this

```
<form method = "POST" action = "{% url 'login' %}">
```

third, I also added form error tags like -

```
{% if form.errors %}
 <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: was googling for ages before I saw this and immediately noticed I had written `form method=" POST"` with a space! Thanks for prompting me to check for typos!

Answer (score 0):

try to edit your 
settings.py...
put this at the bottom...
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'    #the homepage of your app,
try to login again

Comment: yes, it was set to Home initially. But it was not the problem afterall. anyways, its been solved. Thankyou for your help!